# how to access data of table having two foreign keys in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

i have a table called order_details which is having two foreign keys.
(1.) order_id
(2.) product_id

i have compacted the whole table in my view. when i access the records related to order they are working well but when i try to access the record of products which are foreign as product_id in order_detail table i am getting null.

Table of OrderDetails:

```
Schema::create('order_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->integer('amount');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Model of OrderDetail:

```
 public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Model of Order:

```
 public function orderDetails(){
        return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class);
    }
```

Model of Product:

```
 public function orderDetail(){
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderDetail::class);
    }
```

i have compacted the whole table in $orderDetails on my view. when i try to access data of Order table like this:

```
$orderDetails[0]->Order['total_ammount']
```

its working fine as it is accessing the order model through order_id. but with the same way i try to get data from Product Model using product_id like this

```
$orderDetails[0]->Product['name']
```

its showing me no error but null.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try be correcting these relations

OrderDetail Model

```
// individual row of order_details belongs to single product
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Product Model to OrderDetail

I don't think this relation will be required as it hasto pass through User Model. Even though correct it as

```
public function orderDetails() {
    return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class);
}
```